# como seleccionar datos de una segunda tabla segun el usuario

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Cómo puedo seleccionar el usuario que inicia sesión para mostrar el nombre en php, la tabla 1 es para los usuarios principales, y la tabla 2 es para usuarios adicionales, ralacionados con el usuario principal por ID e ID_ppl

Necesito mostrar en php el nombre de usuario que inicia sesión. pero solo me muestra el usuario principal, aunque inicio sesión con un usuario adicional, se debe mostrar el nombre de usuario adicional.

Por ejemplo, me conecto con ** Juana ** y en php me muestran ** Andres **, el usuario principal; cuando me debe mostrar el nombre de Juana

Table 1 usuarios principales

```
id |  usuario  | password | token | nivel | estado | 
----------------------------------------------------
1  | Andres    | *****    | e12A1 | 1     | on     |
----------------------------------------------------
```

Table 2 usuarios adicionales

```
id |  usuario  | password | token | id_ppl | nivel | estado |
-------------------------------------------------------------
1  | Juana     | *****    |       | 1      | 2     | on     |
-------------------------------------------------------------
2  | Martin    | *****    |       | 1      | 2     | off    |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Php query

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT T1.id, T1.usuario, T1.token, T1.nivel, T1.estado FROM escolar AS T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN users_extra AS T2 ON T1.id = T2.id_ppl");

    $stmt->bind_param("ss",$usuario, $password); 
     $stmt->execute(); 
     $stmt->store_result(); 
     if($stmt->num_rows > 0){ 
     $stmt->bind_result($id, $usuario, $token, $nivel, $estado);
     $stmt->fetch();

    $user = array(
     'id' => $id,
     'usuario' => $usuario,
     'token' => $token,
     'nivel' => $nivel,
     'estado' => $estado
     );
```

Comment: Debes cambiar `T1.usuario`  por `T2.usuario` para que seleccione la columna `usuario` de la tabla `users_extra`...

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que en el `SELECT` no estás seleccionando la columna de la tabla `users_extra` sino la de la tabla `escolar`.

Si quieres que te muestre la columna `usuario` de la segunda tabla debes indicarlo en el `SELECT` del siguiente modo:

```
$sql="SELECT 
           T1.id, 
           T2.usuario, 
           T1.token, 
           T1.nivel, 
           T1.estado 
FROM escolar AS T1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN users_extra AS T2 ON T1.id = T2.id_ppl";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
```

Ahí la segunda columna del `SELECT` vendrá de `T2` que es el alias de la tabla `users_extra`.